# Identifier expected in java

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program in java:

```
public class Will {

    int static square(int x) {
        int y = x * x;
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number...");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int result = Will.square(n);
        System.out.println("Square of " + n + " is " + result);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I'm getting those errors:

```
square.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
         int static square (int x)
            ^
square.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
         int static square (int x)
                    ^
2 errors
```

How to resolve those?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to be:

```
static int square (int x)
```

i.e the return-type has to be after the access-modifiers and before the method name.

Answer (score 1):

Change it like

```
public/private/protected(Access specifier) static int square(int x)
```

as per `JAVA standard rules`